# Firebase bug: calling updateChildValues makes other calls slower over time (persistently)

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been hitting a bug with Firebase Database for a month now and I'm still waiting on a resolution. Their support told me to ask here for help...

The problem is, calling `updateChildValues` makes the following calls to `observeSingleEventOfType` persistently slower. What I mean by persistently is that the time increases. You can even stop calling `updateChildValues` and the time increase will continue to exist.

To reproduce, just setup Firebase, create a new Xcode project (I'm using [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org)) and use this code in your `AppDelegate`:

```
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        let userID = "..."

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/users/\(userID)/chatIDs").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            let chatID = snapshot.key

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/messages/\(chatID)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
                snapshot.ref.child("/messages").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    snapshot.ref.updateChildValues(["state": "Received"])
                })
            })
        })

        test1()

        return true
    }

    func test1() {
        let t0 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("/users/facebook:817551771701145/chatIDs").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            let t1 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            print()
            print("---- here: \(t1 - t0)")
            print()
        })
    }

}
```

Then run the app, close it and run again. Repeat this a few times and watch the time printed to the console, it will increase indefinitely.

Detail: run on iPhone 6 simulator. The problem was happening for me on iPhone 5 (the real device), but not in the iPhone 6S simulator. Then I managed to reproduce in the iPhone 6 simulator too.

Comment: Is the device connected to the network?

Comment: Yes, it is. (Had to add more characters here for SO to be happy)